# Formatting buttons and nesting ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For the code given below my ultimate objective is to create a monopoly board (The boxes need to be further divided into listviews and gridviews and the center box is what will eventually become the board)

The page appears in landscape mode (if it makes any difference).

However I'm facing the following issues

1. The boxes are aligned at the top of the screen and the text isn't centered at the middle of the screen, even when I manage to bring the button to the bottom by setting heightfactor to 1.55 the text remains where it is and doesn't recenter itself
2. If I try to nest a listview within a grid element to further divide them I get a blank screen where the list should be ( biggest concern )
3. The buttons appear gray despite setting them to blue ( I'm only using the buttons as a placeholder till I code the rest of the app so the appearance doesn't make a difference to me , this is just out of curiosity as the same code for buttons works in my other pages)

```
class StartGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartGameState createState() => _StartGameState();
}

class _StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: <Widget>[
                FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.7,
                    heightFactor: 1.55,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('left'),
                          onPressed: null),
                    )),
                FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 1.55,
                    heightFactor: 1.55,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: RaisedButton(onPressed: null)),
                FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.7,
                    heightFactor: 1.55,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('right'),
                          onPressed: null),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get the problem wrong you can do this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StartGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartGameState createState() => _StartGameState();
}

class _StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Colum aligns widgets vertically
        child: Column(
          // You can align columns with these. TRY IT YOURSELF
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
           Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
              child: Text("Colum"),
            ),
            // To leave a space of height 5
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            // Row aligns widgets horizontally
            Row(
              // You can align Row with these. TRY IT YOURSELF
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // MediaQuery.of(context).size.width=>Screen Width
                  //MediaQuery.of(context).size.height => Screen Height
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Left"),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                  child: FlatButton(
                   child: Text("Middle"),
                   onPressed: null,
                 ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Right"),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
               )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
              child: Text("Colum 2"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works a lot better than my previous code!
I swapped around row/column and height/width and played around with the values a bit to make it work for landscape but am facing one issue.

I further divided the container you labelled center into 3 rows and adjusted the height/width to the max I can , however I'm always getting some white space bw those and the container marked "column" (Aside from the sizedbox of size 5). Any way to overcome this?